# Radius of convergence of power series of $f(z) = \frac{z^{3}-1}{z^{2}+3z-4}$ at $0.$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

The function $f(z) = \frac{z^{3}-1}{z^{2}+3z-4}$ has a power series expansion in a neighborhood of the origin. What is its radius of convergence.

I believe I have to use the ratio test and show that R = $\frac{1}{L}$, which I think is where my algebra is getting the best of me.

Comment: I would consider trying to factorise the numerator and denominator first, before launching into anything further.

Comment: @πr8 that's what I did and found that (z-1) is a root of z$^{3}$-1 which means it's not a singularity that's where I ran into trouble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a meromorphic function, the radius of convergence of the Taylor series centered at some point is just the distance from the closest singularity. $z^2+3z-4$ vanishes at $z=1$ and $z=-4$, but $z=1$ is not a singularity since $z=1$ is also a root of $z^3-1$. So the radius of convergence at the origin is just $\color{red}{\rho=4}$. Counter-proof:

$$\frac{z^3-1}{z^2+3z-4} = \frac{1+z+z^2}{4+z} = z-3+\frac{13}{4+z} = z-3+13\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n z^n}{\color{red}{4}^{n+1}}.$$